# how to use --staging flag in substrate framework?

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

If i try to run the below command:

`./target/release/node-template build-spec --chain staging > stagingSpec.json`

facing the below error:

`Error: Input("Error opening spec file: No such file or directory (os error 2)")`

Is there any guide how to use that staging flag??

Comment: what happens if you just run `./target/release/node-template build-spec --chain staging` ? (just checking it's not something silly like it is not permissioned to save the file to the current dir)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are [the rustdocs](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/latest/sc_cli/struct.BuildSpecCmd.html) for the command, and it's [implementation in the node template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/master/node/src/command.rs#L52-L59) - this looks for specific from your [chain specification](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/master/node/src/chain_spec.rs) file based on what you pass that is configued. In the template at the time of writing, the template only has `dev` and "everything else" mode:

```rust
    fn load_spec(&self, id: &str) -> Result<Box<dyn sc_service::ChainSpec>, String> {
        Ok(match id {
            "dev" => Box::new(chain_spec::development_config()?),
            "" | "local" => Box::new(chain_spec::local_testnet_config()?),
            path =>
                Box::new(chain_spec::ChainSpec::from_json_file(std::path::PathBuf::from(path))?),
        })
    }
```

Thus you would need to specify another in`/node/src/chainspec.rs` and configure the `/node/src/commnad.rs` to use the correct one when called.